# Macros for auto-refresh of pivot-tables

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, refresh, olap-cube

I have a huge Excel file with lots of pivot tables (from olap-cubes)- about 5 on every of 20 pages. Every week I need to change the data filters and move them 1 week forward. I have written a macros which does it but only for one pivot table.

```
Sub Weeks_upd()
'
' Weeks_upd Ìàêðîñ
'
' Ctrl+u
'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields( _
        "[Fact data].[Year - Week - day].[Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields( _
        "[Fact data].[Year - Week - day].[Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Fact data].[Year - Week - day].[Week]").&[202025]", _
        "[Fact data].[Year - Week - day].[Week]").&[202026]", _
        "[Fact data].[Year - Week - day].[Week]").&[202027]", _
        "[Fact data].[Year - Week - day].[Week]").&[202028]")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields( _
        "[Fact data].[Year - Week - day].[Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
End Sub
```

How can I expand this macros for all the pivot tables in the file? Or is there one other way to update pivot-tables without actually clicking on every single table?

Comment: Try using the refresh all command? https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/workbook/m/refreshall/

Answer (score 0):

This is an untested proposal, but you seem to have following line of code:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields(...
```

You would like to apply this for all pivot tables in your workbook. Well, I would advise you to run through all worksheets and all pivot tables inside them, both can be done using `For Each` loops, something like:

```
For Each l_sheet in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  For Each l_pivot_table in l_sheet.PivotTables
    l_pivot_table.PivotFields(...
    ...
  Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can create a procedure that receives parameters and apply all pivot tables.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Pv As PivotTable
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    
    For Each Pv In Ws.PivotTables
        setPivot Pv
    Next Pv
        
End Sub

Sub setPivot(Pv As PivotTable)
   Pv.PivotFields( _
        "[Fact data].[Year - Week - day].[Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields( _
        "[Fact data].[Year - Week - day].[Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Fact data].[Year - Week - day].[Week]").&[202025]", _
        "[Fact data].[Year - Week - day].[Week]").&[202026]", _
        "[Fact data].[Year - Week - day].[Week]").&[202027]", _
        "[Fact data].[Year - Week - day].[Week]").&[202028]")
    Pv.PivotFields( _
        "[Fact data].[Year - Week - day].[Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
End Sub
```